# Прекратить работу функции после таймера

Tags: javascript, html, css

пишу некий концепт рулетки, и вот некоторая его часть...

Идея такова: у нас имеется таймер и 3 колонки, пока таймер работает колонки асинхронно заполняются пользователями, после истечения таймера заполнение колонок прекращается

Я написал функцию  startTimer(durationInSeconds), которая запускает таймер и функцию  doSomething(), которая начинает процесс генерации пользователей и заполнения колонок

Итак, вопрос в том как же остановить заполнение колонок после того как таймер перестанет работать?

```js
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.double-color__users-list');

function startTimer(durationInSeconds) {
  const timerElement = document.getElementById('timer');
  const secondsElement = document.getElementById('seconds');
  const millisecondsElement = document.getElementById('milliseconds');

  let totalMilliseconds = durationInSeconds * 1000;
  let remainingMilliseconds = totalMilliseconds;

// Функция запускающая асинхронную генерацию пользователей
  doSomething();

  function updateTimer() {
    const seconds = Math.floor(remainingMilliseconds / 1000);
    const milliseconds = remainingMilliseconds % 1000;

    secondsElement.textContent = String(seconds);
    millisecondsElement.textContent = String(milliseconds).padStart(3, '0');

    if (remainingMilliseconds <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      timerElement.textContent = 'Spin!'
      if (!isActive) console.log(123);
    } else {
      remainingMilliseconds -= 10;
    }
  }

  updateTimer(); // Обновляем таймер сразу, чтобы избежать мигания 0.000.

  const timerInterval = setInterval(updateTimer, 10); // Обновляем таймер каждые 10 миллисекунд.

}
// Запускаем таймер на 30 секунд (30000 миллисекунд).
startTimer(10);


class UserBet {
  constructor(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price
  }

  addUserBet(list) {
    const item = `
    <li class="double-color__users-item">
    <img class="double-color__users-avatar" src="./img/header/header-avatar.png" alt="avatar icon">
    <p class="double-color__users-name">${this.name}</p>
    <span class="double-color__users-price">${this.price}$</span>
  </li>
    `
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item)
  }
}

function getRandomInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function doSomething() {
  lists.forEach(list => {
    setInterval(() => {
      new UserBet('user', 12.03).addUserBet(list)
    }, getRandomInterval(1500, 2000));
  })

  // Генерируем новый интервал в диапазоне от 1 до 2 секунд и устанавливаем его
  const randomInterval = getRandomInterval(1500, 2000); // Миллисекунды
  setTimeout(doSomething, randomInterval);

}
```

```css
@import url("./reset.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #171d39;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#timer {
  background-color: #222e54;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.double-color {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.double-color__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
       column-gap: 20px;
}
.double-color__col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 15px;
}
.double-color__users-list {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.double-color__select {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background-color: #222e54;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.double-color__select-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.double-color__select-circle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.double-color__select-multiply {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.double-color__select-submit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.double-color__users {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #222e54;
}
.double-color__users-header {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.double-color__users-totalprice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
       column-gap: 10px;
}
.double-color__users-totalprice img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.double-color__users-totalprice p {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.double-color__users-totalprice span {
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.double-color__users-amount {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}
.double-color__users-amount span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.double-color__users-item {
  padding: 10px 21px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.double-color__users-item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}
.double-color__users-avatar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
.double-color__users-name {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.double-color__col--blue .double-color__users-totalprice span {
  background: #5eb1fd;
}
.double-color__col--blue .double-color__users-header {
  background: rgba(94, 177, 253, 0.6);
}
.double-color__col--blue > .double-color__select {
  background: rgba(94, 177, 253, 0.6);
}
.double-color__col--blue > .double-color__select > .double-color__select-circle {
  background: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}
.double-color__col--blue > .double-color__select > .double-color__select-circle::after {
  background: #5eb1fd;
}
.double-color__col--blue > .double-color__select .double-color__select-submit {
  background: rgb(94, 177, 253);
}

.double-color__col--green .double-color__users-totalprice span {
  background: rgb(94, 253, 115);
}
.double-color__col--green .double-color__users-header {
  background: rgba(94, 253, 115, 0.6);
}
.double-color__col--green > .double-color__select {
  background: rgba(94, 253, 115, 0.6);
}
.double-color__col--green > .double-color__select > .double-color__select-circle {
  background: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}
.double-color__col--green > .double-color__select > .double-color__select-circle::after {
  background: #79fd5e;
}
.double-color__col--green > .double-color__select .double-color__select-submit {
  background: rgb(94, 253, 115);
}

.double-color__col--yellow .double-color__users-totalprice span {
  background: rgba(224, 210, 7, 0.986);
}
.double-color__col--yellow .double-color__users-header {
  background-color: rgba(249, 201, 120, 0.6);
}
.double-color__col--yellow > .double-color__select {
  background: rgba(249, 201, 120, 0.6);
}
.double-color__col--yellow > .double-color__select > .double-color__select-circle {
  background: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}
.double-color__col--yellow > .double-color__select > .double-color__select-circle::after {
  background: rgba(253, 250, 94, 0.8901960784);
}
.double-color__col--yellow > .double-color__select .double-color__select-submit {
  background: rgba(224, 210, 7, 0.986);
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Random</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="timer">
    <span id="seconds">0</span>.<span id="milliseconds">00</span>
  </div>

  <section class="double-color">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="double-color__wrapper">
        <div class="double-color__col double-color__col--blue">
          <div class="double-color__select">
            <div class="double-color__select-circle"></div>
            <span class="double-color__select-multiply">X2</span>
            <button class="double-color__select-submit">0.00$</button>
          </div>
          <div class="double-color__users">
            <div class="double-color__users-header">
              <p class="double-color__users-amount">
                <span>12</span> players
              </p>
              <div class="double-color__users-totalprice">
                <img src="./img/dollar.png" alt="dollar icon">
                <p>TOTAL:</p>
                <span>6.65$</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="double-color__users-list">

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="double-color__col double-color__col--yellow">
          <div class="double-color__select">
            <div class="double-color__select-circle"></div>
            <span class="double-color__select-multiply">X14</span>
            <button class="double-color__select-submit">0.00$</button>
          </div>
          <div class="double-color__users">
            <div class="double-color__users-header">
              <p class="double-color__users-amount">
                <span>12</span> players
              </p>
              <div class="double-color__users-totalprice">
                <img src="./img/dollar.png" alt="dollar icon">
                <p>TOTAL:</p>
                <span>6.65$</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="double-color__users-list">

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="double-color__col double-color__col--green">
          <div class="double-color__select">
            <div class="double-color__select-circle"></div>
            <span class="double-color__select-multiply">X2</span>
            <button class="double-color__select-submit">0.00$</button>
          </div>
          <div class="double-color__users">
            <div class="double-color__users-header">
              <p class="double-color__users-amount">
                <span>12</span> players
              </p>
              <div class="double-color__users-totalprice">
                <img src="./img/dollar.png" alt="dollar icon">
                <p>TOTAL:</p>
                <span>6.65$</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="double-color__users-list">

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант:

Создайте глобальную переменную:

```
let timers = [];
```

Измените функцию `doSomething()`, добавив **id**, в который будет передаваться id таймера и далее добавляться в массив **timers**

Так же в функции надо отключить или переделать строку `setTimeout(doSomething, randomInterval)` т.к. она порождает множественные запуски функции doSomething

```
  function doSomething() {
    lists.forEach(list => {
        const id = setInterval(() => {
          new UserBet('user', 12.03).addUserBet(list)
        }, getRandomInterval(1500, 2000));
        timers.push(id);
    })

    // Генерируем новый интервал в диапазоне от 1 до 2 секунд и устанавливаем его
    const randomInterval = getRandomInterval(1500, 2000); // Миллисекунды
    //setTimeout(doSomething, randomInterval);
  }
```

В функции updateTimer меняем блок if и добавляем остановку таймеров с зачисткой массива.

```
if (remainingMilliseconds <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    timerElement.textContent = 'Spin!'
    timers.forEach(t => clearInterval(t));
    timers = [];
} else {
    remainingMilliseconds -= 10;
}
```

Полный пример кода:

```js
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.double-color__users-list');
let timers = [];

function startTimer(durationInSeconds) {
  const timerElement = document.getElementById('timer');
  const secondsElement = document.getElementById('seconds');
  const millisecondsElement = document.getElementById('milliseconds');

  let totalMilliseconds = durationInSeconds * 1000;
  let remainingMilliseconds = totalMilliseconds;

  // Функция запускающая асинхронную генерацию пользователей
  doSomething();

  function updateTimer() {
    const seconds = Math.floor(remainingMilliseconds / 1000);
    const milliseconds = remainingMilliseconds % 1000;

    secondsElement.textContent = String(seconds);
    millisecondsElement.textContent = String(milliseconds).padStart(3, '0');

    if (remainingMilliseconds <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      timerElement.textContent = 'Spin!'
      timers.forEach(t => clearInterval(t));
      timers = [];
    } else {
      remainingMilliseconds -= 10;
    }
  }

  updateTimer(); // Обновляем таймер сразу, чтобы избежать мигания 0.000.

  const timerInterval = setInterval(updateTimer, 10); // Обновляем таймер каждые 10 миллисекунд.

}
// Запускаем таймер на 30 секунд (30000 миллисекунд).
startTimer(10);


class UserBet {
  constructor(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price
  }

  addUserBet(list) {
    const item = `
    <li class="double-color__users-item">
    <img class="double-color__users-avatar" src="./img/header/header-avatar.png" alt="avatar icon">
    <p class="double-color__users-name">${this.name}</p>
    <span class="double-color__users-price">${this.price}$</span>
  </li>
    `
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item)
  }
}

function getRandomInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function doSomething() {
  lists.forEach(list => {
    const t = setInterval(() => {
      new UserBet('user', 12.03).addUserBet(list)
    }, getRandomInterval(1500, 2000));
    timers.push(t);
  })

  // Генерируем новый интервал в диапазоне от 1 до 2 секунд и устанавливаем его
  const randomInterval = getRandomInterval(1500, 2000); // Миллисекунды
  //setTimeout(doSomething, randomInterval);
}
```

```css
@import url("./reset.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #171d39;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#timer {
  background-color: #222e54;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.double-color {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.double-color__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.double-color__col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 15px;
}

.double-color__users-list {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.double-color__select {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background-color: #222e54;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.double-color__select-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.double-color__select-circle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.double-color__select-multiply {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.double-color__select-submit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.double-color__users {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #222e54;
}

.double-color__users-header {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.double-color__users-totalprice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.double-color__users-totalprice img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.double-color__users-totalprice p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.double-color__users-totalprice span {
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.double-color__users-amount {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}

.double-color__users-amount span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.double-color__users-item {
  padding: 10px 21px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.double-color__users-item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}

.double-color__users-avatar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.double-color__users-name {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.double-color__col--blue .double-color__users-totalprice span {
  background: #5eb1fd;
}

.double-color__col--blue .double-color__users-header {
  background: rgba(94, 177, 253, 0.6);
}

.double-color__col--blue>.double-color__select {
  background: rgba(94, 177, 253, 0.6);
}

.double-color__col--blue>.double-color__select>.double-color__select-circle {
  background: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}

.double-color__col--blue>.double-color__select>.double-color__select-circle::after {
  background: #5eb1fd;
}

.double-color__col--blue>.double-color__select .double-color__select-submit {
  background: rgb(94, 177, 253);
}

.double-color__col--green .double-color__users-totalprice span {
  background: rgb(94, 253, 115);
}

.double-color__col--green .double-color__users-header {
  background: rgba(94, 253, 115, 0.6);
}

.double-color__col--green>.double-color__select {
  background: rgba(94, 253, 115, 0.6);
}

.double-color__col--green>.double-color__select>.double-color__select-circle {
  background: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}

.double-color__col--green>.double-color__select>.double-color__select-circle::after {
  background: #79fd5e;
}

.double-color__col--green>.double-color__select .double-color__select-submit {
  background: rgb(94, 253, 115);
}

.double-color__col--yellow .double-color__users-totalprice span {
  background: rgba(224, 210, 7, 0.986);
}

.double-color__col--yellow .double-color__users-header {
  background-color: rgba(249, 201, 120, 0.6);
}

.double-color__col--yellow>.double-color__select {
  background: rgba(249, 201, 120, 0.6);
}

.double-color__col--yellow>.double-color__select>.double-color__select-circle {
  background: rgba(23, 29, 57, 0.5);
}

.double-color__col--yellow>.double-color__select>.double-color__select-circle::after {
  background: rgba(253, 250, 94, 0.8901960784);
}

.double-color__col--yellow>.double-color__select .double-color__select-submit {
  background: rgba(224, 210, 7, 0.986);
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <span id="seconds">0</span>.<span id="milliseconds">00</span>
</div>

<section class="double-color">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="double-color__wrapper">
      <div class="double-color__col double-color__col--blue">
        <div class="double-color__select">
          <div class="double-color__select-circle"></div>
          <span class="double-color__select-multiply">X2</span>
          <button class="double-color__select-submit">0.00$</button>
        </div>
        <div class="double-color__users">
          <div class="double-color__users-header">
            <p class="double-color__users-amount">
              <span>12</span> players
            </p>
            <div class="double-color__users-totalprice">
              <img src="./img/dollar.png" alt="dollar icon">
              <p>TOTAL:</p>
              <span>6.65$</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="double-color__users-list">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="double-color__col double-color__col--yellow">
        <div class="double-color__select">
          <div class="double-color__select-circle"></div>
          <span class="double-color__select-multiply">X14</span>
          <button class="double-color__select-submit">0.00$</button>
        </div>
        <div class="double-color__users">
          <div class="double-color__users-header">
            <p class="double-color__users-amount">
              <span>12</span> players
            </p>
            <div class="double-color__users-totalprice">
              <img src="./img/dollar.png" alt="dollar icon">
              <p>TOTAL:</p>
              <span>6.65$</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="double-color__users-list">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="double-color__col double-color__col--green">
        <div class="double-color__select">
          <div class="double-color__select-circle"></div>
          <span class="double-color__select-multiply">X2</span>
          <button class="double-color__select-submit">0.00$</button>
        </div>
        <div class="double-color__users">
          <div class="double-color__users-header">
            <p class="double-color__users-amount">
              <span>12</span> players
            </p>
            <div class="double-color__users-totalprice">
              <img src="./img/dollar.png" alt="dollar icon">
              <p>TOTAL:</p>
              <span>6.65$</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="double-color__users-list">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)